# How to graph a solid

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Given a solid described by $S = \{(x,y,z)|0\le x\le4-y^2, -2\le y\le2, 0\le z\le y+2\}$,
how do I graph the solid? I have already tried a `RegionPlot3D` but I might have entered it incorrectly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Define the region

```
R = ImplicitRegion [0 <= x <= 4 - y^2 && -2 <= y <= 2 && 0 <= z <= y + 2, {x, y, z}]
```

and plot it

```
RegionPlot3D[R]
```

[image]

Comment: Just for completeness, a direct `RegionPlot3D[0 <= x <= 4 - y^2 && -2 <= y <= 2 && 0 <= z <= y + 2, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 4}]` does the same thing.

Comment: Not completely the same, because you have to provide the axes ranges !

Comment: Yes, of course. Your method is easier in that respect.